# Redirect my weebly site to my heroku app

Tags: redirect, heroku, dns, weebly

I recently acquired a domain while buying a logo and some business cards through logomaker.com. I took this opportunity to claim the domain that I want to use for my rails app on heroku (Was this a mistake?).

Currently I seem to be required to use Weebly to edit the site for this new domain (But I'm thinking about transferring the domain to my GoDaddy account for simplicity. Is this a good idea?) I'm trying to route the simple domain to my rails app. In other words, I want users to be able to type mrzschool.com and get routed to mrzschool.herokuapp.com. I haven't been able to find a way to do this through Weebly.

I also have access to DNS and nameserver settings, such as imap and pop, through logomaker.com. This seems like it might be a way to change the routing, but I'm realizing that I'm unschooled in the realm of domains and DNS.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you go through the the process of moving your domain registrar from logomaker to your goDaddy account, were you can keep an eye on this domain along side any other domains you've there. It's a tedious process but worth it in my opinion. However, it's optional since you have all the control you need to do that via logomaker.

The heroku docs mentions (found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain)) how you can point your own custom domain to your heroku app subdomain. Keep in mind that you will need to verify your account and your ownership of the domain.

You will also find some useful troubleshooting steps [here](https://kb.heroku.com/what-is-the-correct-dns-cname-target-for-my-custom-domains).